# Error " Sequential.fromConfig called without an array of configs "

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I  am using tensorflow js to load a model from keras following [This Guideline](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-keras.html)
However on this line of code

```
const model = await tf.loadModel('https://foo.bar/tfjs_artifacts/model.json');
```

I am getting the error

```
Error: Sequential.fromConfig called without an array of configs
at new t (app.js:26972)
at t.fromConfig (app.js:26972)
at deserializeKerasObject (app.js:26972)
at deserialize (app.js:26972)
at app.js:26972
at app.js:26972
at Object.next (app.js:26972)
at o (app.js:26972)
```

What can I do to fix it . What can be the possible reasons for this error ?
Thanks for the help .

Note:I have enabled cors in my server so I don't think its a problem related to
my server . I am using a localhost(Not the one mentioned in guideline)
Also as mentioned in the docs I have used

**tfjs.keras.converters.save_keras_model()**

Comment: Did you move all artifact files to the directory the model should be loaded from?

Comment: yes..I have done that

Comment: probably related with [tfjs issue 744](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/744)

Answer (score 1):

As per a comment in https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/744, update your tfjs version:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.13.5"></script>`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd double check your `model.json`. I got this exact same error when I converted *just* my Keras model weights to Tensorflow.js json format (rather than my entire model). i.e. I was saving my Keras model with `model.save_weights(filepath)` rather than `model.save()`.

Your problem may not be the same as mine, but it's probably something to do with your actual model rather than anything to do with the loading of said model.

Comment: The docs say to use [tfjs-converter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter) converter i have used that ....  i have used that ... and I am using keras with tensorflow

Comment: Yes, I used the tfjs-converter too. But you can use that converter on *any* model file, and some of the model files generated by Keras won't work with Tensorflow.js. That's the point I was trying to make in my post.

Comment: @micah5 How did you solved the issue? I am getting a similar problem.

Comment: @GAUTAMKISHORESHAHI Hi, I saved my model with`model.save()` and everything was smooth sailing from here

Comment: @micah5 thank you very much. I will also try it, did you save your the model just after model.fit() or after testing the model. Is it possible to look at your code(if it's uploaded somewhere)?

Comment: @GAUTAM KISHORE SHAHI Unfortunately I can't remember as I did this last year and I haven't used tensorflow.js for a while now. I also don't remember which code I have which implemented this, sorry :(